# DDR4-2933 data transfer rate

Tags: memory, computer-architecture, bitrate, memory-speed

DDR4-2933 functionates at 2933 MHz
How do I find peak data transfert rate in GB/s from there ?

Is it vendor/capacity dependent ? Is there a universal conversion approach ?

It should be something such as (frequency (Mhz))*(amount of data (GB)) = transfer rate (GB/s)

**EDIT**:

I find a hint to some industry name PC4-xxxxx where number after PC4 is data transfer rate in MB/s, would you confirm ? For DDR4-2933 I find PC4-23366 which would be 23366 MB/s = 23366 / 1024 GB /s = 22.9 GB/s.

Comment: Any DDR4 DRAM would have peak data transfer rate significantly less than the theoretical maximum of the interface (which you have mentioned in your edit). DRAM memories due to their architecture are unable to provide data at the maximum rate that the interface supports. The actual peak data rate would depend on the architecture and memory latency values which are device specific.

Answer (score 0):

The actual module frequency is 1466MHz, 2933 is the "effective" data rate due to it being DDR (*Double* Data rate) and DDR modules can transfer 64-bits of data at a time.

The calculation is therefore

```
2933Mhz × 64bit = 187,712 Mbits/s
```

We divide by 8 to go from megabits to megabytes.

```
187,712 / 8     = 23,464 Megabytes/s
```

This agrees with the [Wikipedia DDR4 modules section](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR4_SDRAM#Modules) and also closely matches your PC4-23366, though that Wikipedia page states it should actually be PC4-23466.